# how to make video module with nodejs like facebook did with photos

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg, html5-video, video-processing

Just wondering how to start ? The needs :

With around 10 photos, being able to produce a small video of 5-10sec, with animations for example (transition ?), i want to reproduce the facebook videos process if anybody know about that, which technical stack is the best, modules (ffmpeg, wrapper ffmpeg)(python, nodejs).

Thx

Comment: What exactly is the "facebook videos process"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with this answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg/834035#834035

Specifically the ffmpeg blend filter example:

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 001.png \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 002.png \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 003.png \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 004.png \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i 005.png \
-filter_complex \
"[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v]; \
[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v]; \
[3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b3v]; \
[4:v][3:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b4v]; \
[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v][b4v][4:v]concat=n=9:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

This will give you an output mp4, where each image lasts for one second, with a 0.5 second fade between images.

```
-t 1
```

That is the duration for the image

```
T,0.5
```

Is your fade time

If you're looking to use node, I would recommend the fluent-ffmpeg library: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

I like node as a solution because you can use a single threaded concurrent event loop, which will pass jobs to your ffmpeg module, and allow ffmpeg to take up all of the available cores on your machine.

You might have a function that looks something like this:

```
function runFfmpeg({inputParams, input, outputParams, output}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const ffmpegCommand = new ffmpeg()
        ffmpegCommand.input(input)
        .inputOptions(inputParams)
        .on('start', (command) => {
            // log start
        })
        .on('progress', (progress) => {
            // log progress
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            resolve('SUCCESS!')
        })
        .on('error', (error) => {
            reject(error)
        })
        .outputOptions(outputParams)
        .output(output)
        .run()
    })
}
```

So that just wraps your ffmpeg processes in a promise, and it will resolve on completion and reject on error. You would hand that function your command line input parameters, input files, output parameters, and output file... at least something like that. You might have to adapt that for multiple inputs, but their github is very well documented!

Comment: Thx for ur response, will check this out :)